# "Property [left_b] does not exist on this collection instance laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to insert data only in 3 rows .

i have tried

```
$currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->limit(3)->get();
```

but getting following error

**"Property [left_b] does not exist on this collection instance**

here is full code of function:

```
function updateDepositBV($id, $deposit_amount)
{
    while($id !="" || $id != "0") {
        if(isMemberExists($id))
        {
            $posid = getParentId($id);
            if($posid == "0")
                break;
            $position = getPositionParent($id);

 $currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->limit(3)->get();


            if($position == "R"){
                $new_lbv = $currentBV->left_bv ;
                $new_rbv = $currentBV->right_bv + request()->input('lend_amount');
```

Comment: where does the `$currentBV` come from? (aka where it is defined and how it enters the scope of this function)

Comment: please check question updated

Comment: Allright, `$currentBV` is a `collection` (aka `array`) that contains a maximum of 3 `MemberExtra` model instances, you will need to loop them one by one in order to use the `->`'s to update their values.

Comment: Please can you write a breif answer